# How to sum a measure value in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to create a measure which will be the sum of another measure. But in my output, I'm getting the count of the rows

Below are the DAX queries used

```
  Measure:- 
  "name": "Netsales",
  "expression": "SUM(Sales[SalesQuantity])-SUM(Return[ReturnQuantity])"

  Helper Measure:- 
  "name": "Helper",
  "expression":
  "CALCULATE(IF(([Netsales]=0),BLANK(),SUMX(DISTINCT(Return[Dealer]),1)))"

  Main Measure:- 
  "name": "Returndealer",
  "expression":SUMX(Sales,[helper])
```

Attached images show the result of each measure. The expected output for the Main measure should be 2. But couldn't achieve it. Could anyone please help me with this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without the helper function. The first will assume your visual provides row context for the calculation, the second one enforces it through SUMX().

```
Version 1 = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Sales' ) ;
    FILTER( 'TabSalesle' ; [Netsales] > 0 )
)
```

```
Version 2 = 
SUMX (
    'Sales' ;
    IF ( [Netsales] > 0 ; 1 ; 0 )
)
```

Comment: The above queries didn't work. I have tried in another way which gave me the expected output (Query added as answer). Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the expected output using below query

```
IF(HASONEVALUE(Return[Dealer]),[helper],SUMX(VALUES(Return[Dealer]),[helper]))
```